# How to generalize f# option?

Tags: generics, f#

I'm getting result of some calculations in form of `'a option when 'a :> IBaseType`. There is tree of types derived from `IBaseType`, and I don't really know option of what particular type this one is, but the important thing is that it's option of specific derived, not base type. So I want to upcast it to `IBaseType option` to process it further. As option is generic type, it's impossible to do cast directly (in F#), and I have to do cast inside of Option.map. Nothing complicated, type inference works as expected...
[image: inference ok]
intermediate casted option is also resolved as expected...
[image: intermediate inference ok]
until function is complete. At this point for some reason type inference decided that original option must be already of type `IBaseType option`:
[image: inference not ok]

Intermediate type was already resolved earlier, why did it decided to reassign infered type of the `op`? Sure this leads to runtime exceptions. Looks like compiler error, but the main rule is that there are no errors in compiler.

So in the end it sounds really stupid: I'm out of ideas how to simply upcast simple option. Just to make picture clearer: `processResult` takes `IBaseType option` as argument. And here is source of troublesome function:

```
(fun (x: obj) -> 
    let op = x :?> _ option
    let upcastOp = op |> Option.map (fun y -> y :> IBaseType)
    upcastOp |> processResult)
```

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: Which editor is this? Looks terribly familiar, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Are you able to change `processResult` to accept `option<#IBaseType>`?

Comment: @RamonSnir: That's Visual Studio, just with few tweaks: [Sons of Obsidian theme](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian-modified-for-resharper), [Envy Code R font](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released) and [View Whitespace on](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/05/9990405.aspx).

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I am. But there is not lot of use of it: type inference still decides that op has to be IBaseType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the type of `op` is inferred here.
But I'm pretty sure that if you can't change the type of `x` to `IBaseType option` as suggested by kvb, you really have to use reflection.

A alternative reflection-based solution:

```
let f (x:obj) =
   match x with
   | null -> None  // x is None
   | _ -> match x.GetType().GetProperty("Value") with
          | null -> None  // x is not an option
          | prop ->  
               let v = prop.GetValue( x, null )
               Some (v :?> IBaseType)
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you producing the boxed objects in the first place?  The easiest solution would be to box an `IBaseType option` rather than boxing `#IBaseType option`s to begin with.  If that's not feasible for some reason, then you'll probably need to use reflection.  The issue is that in this block of code:

```
let op = x :?> _ option
let upcastOp = op |> Option.map (fun y -> y :> IBaseType)
```

the compiler knows that `op` is a `'a option when 'a :> IBaseType` for some `'a` but there's nothing that allows the compiler to figure out what `'a` actually is because this type isn't reflected in the final output of your function - the compiler needs to commit to a *specific* type for `'a`, and the best guess it can make is just the base type `IBaseType`.  You would need to do something like this instead:

```
type ResultProcessor =
    static member ProcessResult<'a when 'a :> IBaseType> (op:'a option) =
        let upcastOp = op |> Option.map (fun y -> y :> IBaseType)
        upcastOp |> processResult

fun (x:obj) ->
    let ty = x.GetType()  // must be option<something>
    let [| tyArg |] = ty.GetGenericArguments()
    typeof<ResultProcessor>.GetMethod("ProcessResult").MakeGenericMethod(tyArg).Invoke(null, [|x|])
```

Comment: The initial value itself is result of reflection execution. And I have no impact on result type. And regarding type inference - it's still not clear to me why type inference decides that op have to have that particular type. There is nothing added by final statement to knowledge about it.

Comment: @AndriyK - What reflective call are you making to generate the value?  Can you modify the method that is being called reflectively so that it returns an `IBaseType option` instead of a `SomeSubType option`?  If so, that will be easiest.

Comment: +1 I think I wrote a function like this number of times when dealing with various F# types using reflection :-) This reflective approach also works nicely for other types than options, which is nice if you run into a similar situation with e.g. F# lists.

Comment: @kvb: I'm unable to modify originally called functions. Yes, it would be the easiest option, but the trick is that I can't.

Answer (score 1):

I support kvb's solution. Now, in some benchmarks I did for similar code, for absolute performance I found it an advantage to avoid dynamic (unknown) method invocations. Somehow making new instantiations of generic types is faster. For example:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type BaseResultProcessor() =
    abstract member ProcessResult : obj -> option<IBaseType>

[<Sealed>]
type ResultProcessor<'T when 'T :> IBaseType>() =
    inherit BaseResultProcessor()
    override this.ProcessResult(x: obj) =
        match x :?> option<'T> with
        | Some x -> Some (x :> IBaseType)
        | None -> None

module Example =
    let run (x: obj) =
        let ty = x.GetType()
        let tyArg = ty.GetGenericArguments().[0]
        let p =
            typedefof<ResultProcessor<_>>.MakeGenericType(tyArg)
            |> Activator.CreateInstance :?> BaseResultProcessor
        p.ProcessResult(x)
```

As to what is the problem, the following "intuitive" reasoning is invalid in .NET:

```
'T1 :> 'T2
--------------------------
option<'T1> :> option<'T2>
```

I would say this is typical of type systems - things that appear easy or intuitive are difficult or impossible to implement correctly once you take into account their interactions with the type system as a whole.